# Why is property.fget a read-only attribute?

Tags: python, properties

I'm currently patching a property of a class from a library to make it more versatile.

I'm doing this using the following code which works fine:

```
_orig_is_xhr = BaseRequest.is_xhr.fget
_orig_is_xhr_doc = BaseRequest.is_xhr.__doc__
BaseRequest.is_xhr = property(lambda self: _orig_is_xhr(self) or
    '_iframe-xhr' in request.form, doc=_orig_is_xhr_doc)
```

However, it would be much nicer if i could simply overwrite the getter function so the docstring is preserved:

```
_orig_is_xhr = BaseRequest.is_xhr.fget
BaseRequest.is_xhr.fget = lambda self: (_orig_is_xhr(self) or
    '_iframe-xhr' in request.form)
```

This doesn't work because `property.fget` is a read-only attribute (`TypeError: readonly attribute` when trying to assign to it).
I'm curious if there is a special reason for this or it the python developers just thought it makes no sense to modify a property after creating it without replacing it with a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably right, that it's just a convention to make those attributes read-only, chosen to make the property "all-or-nothing".  Seems it'd be a bit more "Pythonic" to allow these to be assigned after the fact, but can't find the rationale in the [Python 2.2 release notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#property) (when properties were introduced).

In [Objects/descrobject.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r271/Objects/descrobject.c?view=markup) the property's member attributes are defined as read-only:

```
    static PyMemberDef property_members[] = {
        {"fget", T_OBJECT, offsetof(propertyobject, prop_get), READONLY},
        {"fset", T_OBJECT, offsetof(propertyobject, prop_set), READONLY},
        {"fdel", T_OBJECT, offsetof(propertyobject, prop_del), READONLY},
        {"__doc__",  T_OBJECT, offsetof(propertyobject, prop_doc), READONLY},
        {0}
    };
```

Aside: if you replace `READONLY` with `0` and compile, that's all it takes to allow `fget, fset, ..` to be assigned:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
    prop = property(lambda self: self.flag)

obj = Test()
print obj.prop
Test.prop.fget = lambda self: not self.flag
print obj.prop
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Heh, nice - I'm not going to hack the python source though :p

Comment: Of course :-)  I was just pointing out there isn't anything more exotic behind the read-only-ness.

Comment: Mutable properties would create some scary opportunities for unintentional side effects. `Thread.ident.fget = Thread.daemon.fget` anyone?

Answer (score 1):

tested with Anaconda 2.3.0 (Python 3.4.3) in an IDLE shell

```
>>> p = property()
>>> p.fget
>>> p.__init__( lambda obj: None )
>>> p.fget
<function <lambda> at 0x0121FF18>
>>> p.fget = lambda obj: None
Tracebabk (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    p.fget = lambda obj: None
AttributeError: readonly attribute
>>>
```

doesn't look so readonly to me ;)